# .NET Core CLI running non-Core App, how does it work?

Tags: .net, multiplatform, .net-core

I'm learning the `dotnet` CLI (as well as .NET Core) and one thing is not clear regarding multi platform targeting. Suppose my project has following section:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
       ...
    },
    "net451": { }
  }
```

And I have net451 installed on my PC. Then I run it:

```
dotnet run -f net451
```

What is used to compile and run the project? Does it call the msbuild from net451 sdk? Can the running app be still considered as .NET Core App?

Some useful link:

[Running .NET Core apps on multiple frameworks and What the Target Framework Monikers (TFMs) are about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/)

Comment: Don't dive too deep. Microsoft is still changing it, and MSBuild will be back.

Comment: Right, That is my problem, I cannot use a tool until I know how it works... I'm trying to overcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is used to compile and run the project? Does it call the msbuild from net451 sdk?

You can find out yourself if you add the `-v` flag to `dotnet`:

```
> dotnet -v run -f net451

Project hwapp (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\net451\rtmapp.exe
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\net451\rtmapp.pdb
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\net451\win7-x64\rtmapp.exe
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\net451\win7-x64\rtmapp.pdb
Compiling hwapp for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1
Running C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-003121\csc.dll" -noconfig @C:\code\hwapp\obj\Debug\net451\dotnet-compile-csc.rsp
Process ID: 4900

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:01.4136972


Running C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\net451\win7-x64\rtmapp.exe
Process ID: 12208
Hello World!

> dotnet -v run -f netcoreapp1.0

Project hwapp (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\rtmapp.dll
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\rtmapp.pdb
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\rtmapp.deps.json
        C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\rtmapp.runtimeconfig.json
Compiling hwapp for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Running C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-003121\csc.dll" -noconfig @C:\code\hwapp\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\dotnet-compile-csc.rsp
Process ID: 12084

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:01.6766971


Running C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\rtmapp.dll
Process ID: 9068
Hello World!
```

Notice that in both cases, csc, the C# compiler, is used directly (it's the .Net Core version of csc, so it's run using `dotnet csc.dll`). The main difference between the two is the .rsp file, which contains additional arguments for csc.

In the `net451` version, the interesting part of it looks like this:

```
-out:"C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\net451\hwapp.exe"
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll"
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.dll"
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll"
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
```

This is what it means to use `net451`: that reference assemblies for .Net Framework 4.5.1 are used to compile the application.

In the `netcoreapp1.0` version, it looks like this (truncated):

```
-out:"C:\code\hwapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\hwapp.dll"
-r:"C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.CSharp\4.0.1\ref\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
-r:"C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VisualBasic\10.0.1\ref\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
-r:"C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.1\ref\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll"
-r:"C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages\System.AppContext\4.1.0\ref\netstandard1.6\System.AppContext.dll"
-r:"C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages\System.Buffers\4.0.0\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Buffers.dll"
-r:"C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages\System.Collections\4.0.11\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Collections.dll"
-r:"C:\Users\Svick\.nuget\packages\System.Collections.Concurrent\4.0.12\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"
```

Notice that [.Net Standard Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) reference assemblies are used instead.

In either case, msbuild is not used at all.

> Can the running app be still considered as .NET Core App?

I don't think so. I'd say it's a .Net Framework app, created using the .Net Core CLI/SDK. Yes, it's confusing.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. So the main difference to old .net stuff is how the compilation is performed, csc.dll vs msbuild. Now when Microsoft promises to bring it back, I suppose there will be two ways of compilation :)

Comment: @neleus nope unless I misunderstood them. When MSBuild is back, everything will be changed to MSBuild based.